# Should I use [sic] when quoting the KJV 1611?

Tags: quotations, archaicisms, religion

I am currently working on a project for my Grade 12 religion class, and it requires (surprise, surprise) Biblical quotations. I have decided to use the 1611 KJV Bible and quote verses with very archaic spelling and grammar.It's within the guidelines.

My question is, do I need to use [sic] every time *u* and *v* are switched, or *i* and *j*? Or every time an *e* is randomly thrown on the end of a word? I will be specifically citing the 1611 KJV parenthetically.

To illustrate, must I write like this?

> “Masters, giue [sic] vnto [sic] your seruants [sic] that which is iust [sic] and equall [sic], knowing that yee [sic] also haue [sic] a Master in heauen [sic].”  (Col. 4:1, KJV 1611)

Comment: If it's clear that it's an archaic version then [sic] is unnecessary and distracting.

Comment: Ask your teacher.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have discovered over the last 12 years of schooling that, generally speaking, only English teachers know anything about English. Even they aren't always knowledgeable. Plus, as I mentioned, I really dislike her, so I certainly wouldn't want to talk to her more than is necessary.

Comment: The use of *sic* is only for errors. If the text in question was not an **error**, but appropriate for when it was written, then *sic* should not be used.

Comment: But you're probably cutting off your nose to spite your face. Making a lot more work for yourself (as well as her), probably prejudicing your results, and missing out on the vital content matter (not seeing the wood for ye treese).

Comment: @JasonBassford - What???  "Sic" means "thus" -- the text is copied as written.  It does not imply an error.

Comment: @HotLicks It's used to **point out** an error in the origina [*sic*] text. Nobody uses it if there *aren't* any errors.

Comment: At most one '[sic]' is needed for a passage. Maybe less.

Comment: @JasonBassford - It's not necessarily an error, just something that's weird (by current standards).

Comment: And, of course, "Sic transit gloria mundi" means "Gloria threw up on the bus on Monday".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should say that littering a text with "[sic]" is unhelpful. If it's obvious what you're quoting, then you're quoting it.

You might cite it as "(Col 4:1, KJV 1611 as printed)" or something.

Certain letters might cause technical difficulties, like  yͤ. Bear in mind also that this is a transliteration, and probably incorrect. Although your text has *giue* because the blackletter *v* looks very much like the modern *u,* complete with a tail, the correct transliteration into modern Roman type as you have here is arguably *v*, because that's the letter which produces the sound the blackletter character did. It's a similar problem with transliterating Cyrillic: is Романовы "Pomahobbi", "Romanov", "Romanev" or "Romanoff"?

If your text had Roman characters, then it would be reasonable to copy those.

You might be interested in the [King James Bible website](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/King-James-Bible-English/) — there is an edition of 1833 which does the Romanisation you want [and could therefore simply be copied verbatim, but is 1833 not 1611]; but note how the 1611 title page spells *out,* *tongues* and *Churches*; the blackletter text for those words would probably not use the look-alike . However, *revised* does use a *u* as well as a long s. Transliteration is not straightforward. If you're going to do it, spend time to get it right. Don't get it wrong **and** annoy your teacher.

Comment: The printed *giue* really does have a *u*, not a blackletter *v* that looks like a *u*. The usage of *u* and *v* was different back then, with *v* used at starts of words (as in *vnto*, quoted by the OP) and *u* elsewhere (e.g. *giue*).

Comment: Exactly, but the matter of transliteration into modern Roman type isn't a straightforward substitution of letters which are superficially similar, as the 1611 title page shows.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did wonder about the substitutions, but are those letters not actually *u* and *v*? Are they some kind of archaic letters that don't exist anymore?

Comment: Why would the KJV Bible be in blackletter? Was that ever common for printed English as opposed to German? The title page shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version) is printed in Roman and Italic typefaces.